# Script code only seems to work on single instance of prefb

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am experiencing the strangest issue
I have a ray cast and when it touches a certain layer it calls my function which does a small animation.

The problem is, this only works on a single object, I have tried duplicating, copying the prefab, dragging prefab to the scene, it doesn't work.

Now I have this code below, and as you can see I have this line which allows me to access the script on `public PlatformFall platfall;` so I can call `platfall.startFall();`

Something I've noticed, If I drag a single item from the hierarchy to the public PlatFall in Inspector then that SINGLE object works as it should. ( in that it animates when startFall is called). HOWEVER, if I drag the prefab from my project to the inspector then they do not work. (Even if debug log shows that the method is called animation does not occur).

```c#
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {
    //JummpRay Cast
    public PlatformFall platfall;
    // LayerMask to determine what is considered ground for the player
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public LayerMask WhatIsFallingPlatform;

    // Transform just below feet for checking if player is grounded
    public Transform groundCheck;

    /*....
    ...*/
    Update(){
        //    Ray Casting to Fallingplatform

        isFallingPlatform = Physics2D.Linecast(_transform.position, groundCheck.position, WhatIsFallingPlatform);
        if (isFallingPlatform)
        {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            platfall.startFall();
        }
        Debug.Log(isFallingPlatform);
    }
}
```

Platform Script

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlatformFall : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float fallDelay = 0.5f;

    Animator anim;

    Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Awake Called");
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start Called");
    }

    //void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    //{
    //    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag);
    //    GameObject childObject = other.collider.gameObject;
    //    Debug.Log(childObject);
    //    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Feet"))
    //    {
    //        anim.SetTrigger("PlatformShake");

    //        Invoke("Fall", fallDelay);

    //        destroy the Log
    //        DestroyObject(this.gameObject, 4);
    //    }
    //}

    public void startFall()
    {


            anim.SetTrigger("PlatformShake");



     Invoke("Fall", fallDelay);
        Debug.Log("Fall Invoked");
        // destroy the Log
  //       DestroyObject(this.gameObject, 4);

    }

    void Fall()
    {
        rb2d.isKinematic = false;
        rb2d.mass = 15;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood from your post that you are always calling PlatformFall instance assigned from inspector. I think this changes will solve your problem.

```c#
public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour {
    private PlatformFall platfall;
    private RaycastHit2D isFallingPlatform;

    void FixedUpdate(){
        isFallingPlatform = Physics2D.Linecast(_transform.position, groundCheck.position, WhatIsFallingPlatform);
        if (isFallingPlatform)
        {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            platfall = isFallingPlatform.transform.GetComponent<PlatformFall>();
            platfall.startFall();
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, i assume that you put prefab to proper position to cast. And one more thing, you should make physics operations ,which affect your rigidbody, in FixedUpdate.

Comment: Works perfectly, what was my error ? because I was not doing it in FixedUpdate?

Comment: nope, your code calls same PlatformFall instance which is assigned from inspector. now, it uses PlatformFall component of hitted object.